# selecting from a table based on a distinct column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

hope this makes sense. I have a table that has a bunch of records in it. Each record has a uniqueID and a localID called pro. UniqueID's never repeat but there can be multiple records with the same localID. I'm trying to build a query where, even though there may be 15 records with the same localID, just show me 1 of them. Anyone, it doesn't matter. How do i pull this off? I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, pro FROM ProLookup WHERE pro LIKE '%" & replace(q,"'","''") & "%'"
```

but that didn't work. The "q" is the query for an end user searching for a pro (localID). I'm not an expert on sql so i'm sure i'm doing something wrong. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with getting the largest ID then this would work.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(id) AS id, 
    pro 
FROM ProLookup 
WHERE pro LIKE '%" & replace(q,"'","''") & "%'"
GROUP BY pro
```

Comment: So the MAX() aggregate function pull the "largest" id.  Since you have more than id for each pro but only want to see one pro, you can use the group by to basically pull each distinct pro and then the max id for each distinct pro.  You could use MIN() to get the smallest id as well.  Also, if you don't actually need the id field then you could have just left it out of the select and then the DISTINCT would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `SELECT TOP 1 id, pro FROM ProLookup WHERE pro LIKE '%" & replace(q,"'","''") & "%'"`

What is exactly wrong with your query? i.e. giving an error or incorrect data.

Is the extra " at the end necessary? SQL Server doesn't especially like double quotes so if that is being passed to the query you may need to remove it depending on your environment.

Comment: This is coming from an asp page. That query would return 1 result.

Comment: @Damien Then the extra " is fine if it is coming straight from asp.  So you didn't want 1 result? If what I'm guessing is right you should have specified in your question that you weren't looking for a specific row, but you were filling an array of sorts.  Try to put your expected results in your question next time to give others a better idea of what you're after. As you can see were my confusion came from.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, pro  
FROM
(
SELECT id, pro , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pro ORDER BY id) AS RN
FROM ProLookup 
WHERE pro LIKE YourCondition    --<-- Only if you want certain Pro ids, if you
)Q                                 -- want all Distinct Pro Ids, take where clause
WHERE RN = 1                       -- Out.
```

Comment: Thanks for responding... i accepted the answer below since it was a lot easier to implement. Thank you!

Comment: No problem pal whatever helps you :)